# Quantmod in R... downloading stock data

Tags: r, quantmod

In the Quantmod package in R, you can download share price data as follows

```
my_portfolio <- c("AAPL", "SBUX")
getSymbols(my_portfolio)
```

And this works fine. I can access the stock data by typing in `AAPL` or `SBUX`. For example

```
> head(AAPL)
           AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
2007-01-03     86.29     86.58    81.90      83.80   309579900         11.34
2007-01-04     84.05     85.95    83.82      85.66   211815100         11.59
2007-01-05     85.77     86.20    84.40      85.05   208685400         11.51
2007-01-08     85.96     86.53    85.28      85.47   199276700         11.56
2007-01-09     86.45     92.98    85.15      92.57   837324600         12.52
2007-01-10     94.75     97.80    93.45      97.00   738220000         13.12
```

... and I can do lots of nice stats in this way.

But this is inconvenient because if I change `my_portfolio`, say by replacing `"AAPL"` with `"IBM"`, then I have to change all future occurrences of `AAPL`'s with `IBM`'s later in the script.

**My Question:**
How can I find the downloaded data associated with `my_portfolio` obtained from `getSymbols` without having to explicitly typing `AAPL` and `SBUX` for a second time?

Comment: Put it in an environment, as demonstrated in `?getSymbols`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be inclined to do it this way:

```
library(quantmod)
my_portfolio <- c("AAPL", "SBUX")
stocks <- lapply(my_portfolio,getSymbols,auto.assign=FALSE)
names(stocks) <- my_portfolio
# access the data
head(stocks[[my_portfolio[1]]])
#            AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
# 2007-01-03     86.29     86.58    81.90      83.80   309579900         11.34
# 2007-01-04     84.05     85.95    83.82      85.66   211815100         11.59
# 2007-01-05     85.77     86.20    84.40      85.05   208685400         11.51
# 2007-01-08     85.96     86.53    85.28      85.47   199276700         11.56
# 2007-01-09     86.45     92.98    85.15      92.57   837324600         12.52
# 2007-01-10     94.75     97.80    93.45      97.00   738220000         13.12
```

So this generates a named list of xts objects containing the stock prices. The list elements have the same names as the stocks in your portfolio.

Unfortunately, the column names are still stock-specific (e.g., `AAPL.Close` rather than just `Close`), but you can overcome that problem using, e.g., the `Cl(...)` function in `quantmod`.

Comment: You can use `sapply` with `simplify=FALSE` to get the same result, but without requiring the `names(stocks) <- my_portfolio` line.  Here's another way to get the results in a list: `getSymbols(my_portfolio, env=e <- new.env()); as.list(e)[my_portfolio]`